# How to add multiple values to file/image fields while creating node programmatically?

Tags: 8, nodes, media

I have multiple images coming dynamically in array. But while adding those images to node only last file get attached in field and other images only saved in file directory. I have tried everything but didn't find any solution. Please help. Please review the code and suggest me the solution.

```
$node = Node::create(['type' => 'my_contentType']);
$node->set('title', $item['name']);
$node->set('field_author_name', $item['author']);
foreach ($FilePaths_keys as $path){
$digitalFile_path = $item['bitstreams'][$path] ['retrieveLink'];
$get_data_contents = file_get_contents($digitalFile_path);
$file = file_save_data($get_data_contents, 'public://'.$item['bitstreams'][$path]['name'], FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE); 
$Dfiles = [
        'target_id' => $file->id(),
        'alt' => $item['bitstreams'][$path]['name'],
        'title' => $item['bitstreams'][$path]['name']
      ];
$node->set('field_book_image', $Dfiles);
}
$node->enforceIsNew();
$node->save();
```

Running this code will save all images in directory but only last image got attached with node. How all the images get attach in "field_book_image" unlimited field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change your code:

```
$Dfiles = [];
foreach ($FilePaths_keys as $path){
  ....
  $Dfiles[] = [
        'target_id' => $file->id(),
        'alt' => $item['bitstreams'][$path]['name'],
        'title' => $item['bitstreams'][$path]['name']
      ];
}
$node->set('field_book_image', $Dfiles);
$node->enforceIsNew();
$node->save();
```

Comment: Thank you...you made my day. Thanks a lot.